# flickr json rest call not working  

Tags: json, flickr

Im using  the [flicker api](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) on an iphone app, its working fine if I use the search method

> NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
>           @"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=%@&tags=%@&per_page=15&format=json&nojsoncallback=1", FlickrAPIKey, text];

where text is the term to search for,, it works ok,

but when I want to look at my photo stream  ["nabe_fan"](http://www.flickr.com/photos/nabe_fan/) ; it doesn work!

here the json call Im using,

> NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getContactsPublicPhotos&api_key=%@&user_id=nabe_fan", FlickrAPIKey];

but it doesnt work with my user name:NataliaBetaFan or with the photostream:nabe_fan

I can check this in the browser too, where when using the user name, gives me user not found,

so How to construct the correct json call to show just the pics in my user, stream,,

thanks a lot!

edit>

solved!
thanks to the below response,
the call looks like this:

> http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=FLICKERKEY&user_id=66591366@N02&per_page=15&format=json&nojsoncallback=1

Comment: This question doesn't really have *anything* to do with the iPhone, since you've already determined that the problem is with the API URL you're using. I think the question would be clearer if you just focused on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [user_id required is the NSID, not the Flickr username](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html).

> **user_id (Optional)**
>
> The NSID of the user who's photo to search. If this parameter
>    isn't passed then everybody's public photos will be searched. A value
>    of "me" will search against the calling user's photos for
>    authenticated calls.

Use [flickr.urls.lookupUser](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.urls.lookupUser.html) to get the NSID first, then use the returned value in your user_id field.